# pubDate from RSS feed

Tags: jquery

I want to check if my pubdate i receive from a RSS feed is older that now.

I do this:

```
var mypubdate = new Date(pubDate);

var mydate = new Date();

if(mydate > mypubdate){
  //yes
}else{
  //no
}
```

but it dosen't work.

pubdate format is: `"Tue, 30 Dec 2014 20:10:00 +0000"`

and mydate format is: `"Tue Dec 30 2014 22:52:54 GMT+0100 (CET)"`

how can I chage the pubdate format, so i can check if the pubdate is older than mydate ?

Comment: It works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/vkg16dxg/ - you dont need to do anything

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. But thank you for your time,